# ViewPager in ListView disappears

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a `ListView` in which i am putting a `ViewPager` in each of its row. Its `getView()` is implemented as follows

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_row_pager, null);
                ViewPager pager=(ViewPager)convertView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
                pager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));


            return convertView;
        }
```

My `ViewPager` has 4 scrollable fragments. [Here](http://pastebin.com/Xuyf0WMg) is my implementation of `FragmentPagerAdapter`

The problem is that the ViewPager appears in only some of the `ListView` rows. On scrolling the `ListView`, the `ViewPager`appears in some of the rows and then they disappear again on further scrolling of `ListView`.

Also,while scrolling the `ViewPager`, only 1 or 2 fragments appear.
I am unable to understand this weird behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use PagerAdapter
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html

or change your **FragmentPagerAdapter** to **FragmentStatePagerAdapter**.

Comment: I suggest you to use Pager Adapter if you're just showing images or doing simple operations in your pager parts.

Comment: How will PagerAdapter ( which property of PagerAdapter) will help in my case?

Comment: Please also state the reason when u post a solution. As in why PagerAdapter will help here? Or the reason for the problem.

Answer (score -1):

The tutorial on [this](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296) page might help you. It says that the list view items which are not visible are recycled. This means you should check first, if the item (in your case the viewpager) was destoyed `if (convertView == null)`. If this is the case you need to reinitialize the viewpager, otherwise you may attempt to restore the existing viewpager. The example from above uses tags for this.

The problem that only one or two fragments appear might be worked around by using `setOffscreenPageLimit(3);`, where 3 + 1 is the overall number of pages. Viewpagers usually only instantiate the currently used fragment and the next fragment to be loaded. The other ones are destroyed when they are "offscreen".

Comment: i AM always initializing the view whether its recycled or not. Isnt that sufficient?

Comment: I am using only 2 items in ListView and both are visible. One has the ViewPager and the other is blank. How will u explain this?

Comment: How are you filling both rows? Post this code as well, please. This way we might rebuild your scenario locally.

Comment: I am filling both rows using getView(). Can you please tell which other code is needed?

Comment: Code for the initialization of the ListView itself.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? Thanks, for the downvote... It seems the other question didn't help you either.